# diff between airflow.providers and airflow.contrib

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am new to python and airflow. was trying to use the Bigquery hook operator and came to know there are two packages for the hook. airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery
airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook . so what is the difference between those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contrib` is deprecated (See [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6e15e3a65ec15d9b52abceed36da9f8cccee72d9/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L31-L35)). You should always use `providers`.
If you will check your logs you will see deprecation warning raised whenever you import from `contrib`.

The reason for this is because previously integrations to services like BigQuery were coupled to Airflow core. This means that new versions were frequent only as Airflow core releases. To avoid that Airflow decoupled each service to its own provider package which is released separately.